# React - history.push is not working- when only query is changed

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have URL like :http://localhost:8000/main/target/:targetId/id/d:id?query=x,y

On an action I need to update url and that am doing using history.push.

now I have two scenarios and one is working other one is not :

- first and working scenario- if history.push tries to update url with new value for :targetId or :id along with url query - then url gets updated and rerendering happens. Things works for me
- second and not working scenario - if :targeted and:id in url remains same and I just try to change the query- url doesnt get updated using history.push.

Need to handle the second scenario and want to update url and update components based on updated url.

Comment: Can you post a reproduction of your problem, please?

Comment: Yep, `history.pushState` works fine for changing only the query, so more info is needed.

Comment: Please add your code

Comment: where's your code??

Comment: I have one action to update url on click:

const onElClick = e => {
    const targetId = e.target;
    const id= e.id;
    const query = `${e.name},${e.color}`
    history.push(
     `/main/target/${targetId}/id/${id}?query=${query}`
    );
  };

And on the target page, I'm using useEffect to capture the change in location search:

useEffect(()=> {
....
}, [window.location.search]);

Answer (score 0):

I have one action to update url on click:

```
const onElClick = e => {
    const targetId = e.target;
    const id= e.id;
    const query = `${e.name},${e.color}`
    history.push(
     `/main/target/${targetId}/id/${id}?query=${query}`
    );
  };
```

And on the target page, I'm using useEffect to capture the change:

```
useEffect(()=> {
....
}, [window.location.search]);
```